# Update completed . No rows changed

Tags: teradata

1 .The below collect stats statment on volatile table in Teradata Bteq script returns no rows changed . Can some one help me to understand whether the stats are collected or not ?.

collect stats on ORDER_VT column (ORDER_ID);

** Update completed. No rows changed.
*** Total elapsed time was 16 seconds.

2.Trying to collect the stats on below volatile created in two different ways .

- Collect stats on all columns at a time
- Collecting stats on each column individually
  Whats make the the difference here .

Create multiset volatile table TEST1
as (
select
COLMN1,
COLMN2,
COLMN3,
from TABLE1   T1
inner join TABLE2 T2
on T1.KEY1=T2.KEY1
AND T1.KEY2=T2.KEY2
)WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(COLMN1,COLMN2,COLMN3)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

```
Collect stats on TEST1 column(COLMN1,COLMN2,COLMN3);
Collect stats on TEST1 column(COLMN1 );
Collect stats on TEST1 column(COLMN2 );
Collect stats on TEST1 column(COLMN3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1: Stats on a Volatile Table are stored in memory only, not in the data dictionary -> no row updated.

#2: The 1st collect creates a multi-column statistics, the other ones are single column.

To see the actual data use `help stats on test1;` and `show stats values on test1;`

Comment: Firstly thanks for the responses . Does it required to collect stats in both ways multi and single on volatile table ?. f we have to chose from both of the situations what should better option? @dnoeth

Comment: Depends on what your doing with this VT, maybe you don't need stats at all...

Comment: Followed by collect stats statements these columns are used in joins .

Comment: run `DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;` and then run an explain on your query. This will give you recommended stats to collect to support that query.